# Initializing c++ string with integer and chars

Tags: string, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str {5, 'c'};
    cout << str;  // "\005c"
}
```

Output: c

With gdb, it confirms that str contains "\005c" with 
str[0] = '\005'
str[1] = 'c'

Why str[0] is not being printed in output console?
Used c++ version: c++11

Comment: ASCII code 5 is not a printable character...

Answer (score 0):

ASCII 5 represents a signal intended to trigger a response at the receiving end. It is not visible on the console. 
Reference: http://ascii.cl/

For example: try 65 instead of 5, you will see 'A'.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I think this is supposed to be a self-answer (not a clarification/comment), so this is the right place for it. (That still leaves open whether this Q/A pair is worth keeping…)

Comment: yes I had figured that out on my own, that's why posted the solution as well. Thanks though. Keeping it as it might help others, perhaps!

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII number 5 is non printable. [ASCII table](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/number-five-ascii-code-53.html)

ASCII representation of 5 which is 53 is printable.

```
string str {53, 'c'};
    cout << str;  // 5c
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [ASCII](http://ascii.cl/) value of `5` is `53`.

So, you can try this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    string str {53, 'c'};
    cout << str;  // "\005c"
}
```